# Finding why a ssh tunnel is not working

Tags: linux, ssh-tunnel

I have a remote server that I can SSH into no problem. I have PostgreSQL (ps) set up on the remote server (called 'enc') and local machine, both running on 5432 (the default). The remote server does not allow connections from outside connections (local web server goes directly to it).

I am trying to set up an SSH tunnel to make running commands on the remote ps server easier than copying files across, logging into the server and running them manually on that end.

I have tried running the following command

```
ssh -N -L 5555:enc:5432 enc
```

The tunnel appears to set up correctly but when I try to connect to the remote machine with

```
psql -p 5555
```

it says it is not working

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5555"?
```

Is this likely a problem with settings on the tunnel or restrictive user permissions (I imagine that the error would be different if that were the case)?

Comment: What OS is this?

Comment: Linux, specifically arch connecting to debian, both with openSSH servers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out he problem was further down the line. The tunnel works correctlty however then trying to connect to postgres you have to pass the -h (even it is for localhost) otherwise it will try to connect over a unix socket (which is right there in the error) and not over tcp (which is the only way it will work with a tunnel).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ssh -N -L 5555:enc:5432 localhost
```

and then

```
lsof -i :5555
```

If you don't see anything there your local machine isn't listening to anything.

Comment: That seems to be working well:
ssh     5941 hyposaurus    4u  IPv6  51698      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:personal-agent (LISTEN)
ssh     5941 hyposaurus    5u  IPv4  51699      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:personal-agent (LISTEN)

Comment: And if you run on the final server `ncat -l -p 5432` and on your end `ncat <server> 5432` does it work as well?

Comment: Not really. On the server (different version I am guessing I have to use ncat -l 54322 since -l and -p are incompatible. That says that the address is already in use.  The local version says the same.

Comment: Readign this http://freddebostrom.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/ssh-tunnel-from-the-command-line/ makes me think I should use ssh -N -L 5555:localhost:5432 enc  but that looks to be the same end regardless, so I am a bit more confused.

Comment: Both should work. Once you connect to enc and there you do the forward to localhost and once you connect to localhost and do a forward to enc. I got my info from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

Comment: ncat usually should not have a problem with -p and -l on the otherhand nc/netcat often acts differently depending on versions that's why i prefer to use ncat since it always behaved the same for me.

Comment: what is the N flag

Answer (score 2):

Type

```
netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep "port_number"
```

in your server machine and look for the ip address in which the service is running.

If it is the machine's ip address you must mention that one in the ssh -L command, else if it is the loopback address (127.0.0.1 - ipv4 or ::1 - ipv6 ) mention that in the command.